# Storing World-space Coordinates

Tags: opengl

When designing objects to be placed in an OpenGL world space, how are the world space coordinates stored with their corresponding objects/models?

I've been using Wavefront Object files for simplicity and I've heard of Collada but haven't been able to find any standard method of saving a world space, as one might if designing a game level.

I am very new to OpenGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A world position, rotation and scale can always be defined as a 4x4 matrix, but it loses some information if you just store it in one matrix. Therefore, the three matrices are stored separated like so:

```
W = Translation * Rotation * Scale
with
    [ 1 0 0 x ]
    [ 0 1 0 y ]
    [ 0 0 1 z ]
T = [ 0 0 0 1 ]

    [ r r r 0 ]
    [ r r r 0 ]
    [ r r r 0 ]
R = [ 0 0 0 1 ]

    [ sx 0  0  0 ]
    [ 0  sy 0  0 ]
    [ 0  0  sz 0 ]
S = [ 0  0  0  1 ]
```

The rotation is quite hard to store in only a single matrix. So most of the time, we use the [Quaternion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) to store a rotation, because it is easier to understand what it does and complies to better calculations. There is a lot that I could explain about [gimbal locks (movie)](http://youtu.be/zc8b2Jo7mno), but you probably need a [reference guide for matrices](http://www.3dcodingtutorial.com/Basic-OpenGL-functions/Translate-and-Rotate-functions.html) and a good [openGL math library](http://glm.g-truc.net/) that contains these data types.

Since OpenGL is not an engine that has some basic GameObject that you can use, you will have to create that class yourself (assuming OOP here). Store the world data in these objects and draw them in the appropriate order. You should not save world data into the 3D model, since you can instantiate multiple objects of the same model (multiple enemies that look the same).

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.spacesimulator.net/wiki/index.php?title=3d_Engine_Programming_Tutorials) that shows you how to create a basic engine.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm familiar with gimbal locks and quaternions. I was not sure whether quaternions or Euler angles were more commonly used. Despite a lot of googling I hadn't come across that tutorial and it looks useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> how are the world space coordinates stored with their corresponding objects/models?

However you like.

OpenGL does not deal with data management. It's completely up to you, to do this.

Comment: Ah, I was beginning to suspect that but thought there might be a standard structure.

Answer (score 1):

Usually they are not. Objects are mostly designed in their own space. Their placement within a "world" is the result of a transformation (translations, rotations) often expressed as a matrix.

If you look at the Collada specification for example, you will see that a scene is a hierarchy  (a DAG) of nodes and possible translations, rotations, scales or skews. I don't think such hierarchies (or scene descriptions) are expressible in the OBJ format.

All in all it does not have a lot to do with OpenGL.

Comment: Collada is a very expansive specification and I've hardly scratched the surface. I'm thinking more about static objects, for example something like a building. I'm comfortable manipulating them but unclear how the actual relative positioning(world-space) of these objects is managed. From the answers given I suspect there is a transformation stored with the object? Is it the model-view transformation that is stored with each object to put it into a world space?

Comment: You need some form of structure to represent your scene. Often a graph structure (referred to as a [scene graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph)) is a sensible choice. This creates a hierarchy of objects and transformations, allowing you to describe a scene with (static) objects and their relative placements. You could either use an existing scene graph library or create something yourself. This is however closely related to the scene hierarchy I mentioned for Collada. And you'll have to manage it yourself somehow. OpenGL does not do it for you.